# why I cannot kill the process group with this c code?

Tags: c, linux, multiprocessing, kill

In the main parent process I called :

```
killpg(child_group, SIGKILL);
```

in the child process, i set the child group as:

```
setsid();
child_group = getpgrp();
```

But I checked the processes, ps shows the process group was not killed. 
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the parent process:

```
killpg(child_group, SIGKILL);
```

How did you actually get `child_group`?

Doing the following in the child process for that purpose is pointless:

```
child_group = getpgrp();
```

That is because this `child_group` is just a copy in the child process (i.e.: the `child_group` in the parent process doesn't get modified)

---

`SIGKILL` has to be send to the *PGID* that corresponds to the child's *PID*, because it becomes a process group leader by means of `setsid()`. That is, as the argument for `killpg()` you should use the `pid_t` returned to the parent process by the call to `fork()`.

Be sure `killpg()` gets called by the parent **after** `setsid()` is (successfully) returned in the child (i.e.: after the child has become a *process group leader* and not before).

---

A minimal example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void parent(pid_t pid) {
    killpg(pid, SIGKILL);
}

void child(void) {
    if (-1 == setsid())
        return;

    while(1) {
        sleep(1);
        printf("child\n");
    } 
}


int main() {
    pid_t pid;
    switch ((pid=fork())) {
    case 0: // child
        child();
        break;

    default: // parent
        // wait some time to let setsid() complete
        sleep(5);
        parent(pid);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I defined a global variable as child_group. So it is accessible for both processes.

Comment: @J.R. No, it is not. Each process has its own copy.

Comment: Thnx. I got it.

Comment: @J.R. I've updated the answer with an example which uses the `pid_t` returned by `fork()` as the argument for `killpg()`.

Comment: There are better alternatives to the `sleep(5)` above, though.

Comment: so actually I do not need the group id to kill the process group? that's bit weird,....

Comment: Yes, but the group id corresponds to PID of the group leader, and the group leader is the child created, because it called `setsid()`.

Comment: Yes. I got the part of setsid or setpgrp. But I always thought the argument of killpg is process group id? Cause I checked the man page of killpg, it said it sends the signal to the process group, So I thought it should be the process group id.

Comment: So it seems the argument is actually the process group leader id. anyway, many thnx!

Comment: Yes, the argument is the *process group id*, and the *process group id* is the *process id* of the *process group leader*, which is the child process after returning from `setsid()`. For that reason you can simply use the value returned by `fork()` to the parent.